# What can we say about the solution of a differential equation which satisfies some properties.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

${d \over dt}{u(t,x)}$=$f(u(t,x))$,

$u(0,x)=g(x)$. If $f,g $ are $C^1$ then what can we say about their solution $u$?

I know the existence and uniqueness theorem but when it is $g(x)= x$  .But  here  how can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The only derivative is with respect to t so x can be treated as a constant or parameter.  You have $du_x/dt= f_x(t)$ which has general solution $u_x(t)= \int_a^t f(s)ds$ where "a" is an undetermined constant.  The condition that $u_x(0)= g(x)$ makes that solution $u_x(t)= \int_0^t f(s)ds+ g(x)$.